# SSD is not showing up in bootloader installation device list while installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, ssd, raid, bootloader

I have Windows 7 installed on my SSD. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the same SSD drive. But when I try to install Ubuntu alongside Windows it shows only the HDD in the drive selection list. If I try to manually select the SSD as the bootloader installation device an error message  is shown `no root file system is defined`, although I chose sda1 as bootloader.

Note that I'm not using RAID array in the SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolved the problem. Created a new partition in SSD with `EXT4` file system and installed ubuntu there.